# Why my `latexmk -cd-` reports an error?

Tags: latexmk

English is not my native tongue, forgive me for some of the wrong expression below.

There is TeXLive 2019 on my 32bit windows 7, and all packages were updated to the latest version. My dirtree is `test/new/main.tex`, and I am in `test` directory. When I use

```
latexmk -cd- -xelatex new/main
```

in cmd, it reports an error.

[image]

However when I use `-cd` option,

```
latexmk -cd -xelatex new/main
```

I compile it successfully.

I test the directory seperator `/`, `\`, `\\`, but none of them worked.

Comment: Well then use the `-cd` option.  Switching into the `new` directory before the compilation is the right thing to do.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yeah I know that, I’m reading the manual of latexmk and saw this option. And when I test it, it report an error. I want to know is there some problem about latexmk or windows?

Comment: well windows uses backslashes for pathes, somewhere in the script the slash is translated to a backslash and then passed to xelatex, and xelatex doesn't like this. But it doesn't matter much why it happens: calling xelatex from outside of the directory is wrong. Even if this error is avoided you will get other errors as files are not correctly found. Switch into the folder.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ok, I understand, thanks

Comment: This problem occurs for the TeXLive distribution, but **not** for the MiKTeX distribution. Latexmk does indeed make the replacement of "/" by "\" when calling programs under MS-Windows, since "/" is in some (rare) cases unacceptable as a directory separator. But because of the issue with TeXLive, there will be an option to turn off the substitution in the next release of latexmk (ver 4.69 or higher).  You can try this out in the pre-release version at  http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8/latexmk/versions.html

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs because by default latexmk substitutes a backslash for a forward slash as a directory separator when invoking programs under MSWin.  This corresponds to the standard form of filenames for MSWin. But doing the substution causes the problem for the version of xelatex (etc) in the TeXLive distribution (but not the MiKTeX version!).  This is because the TeXLive version treats the backslash as introducing a TeX macro name.

You can solve the problem by the following setting

```
$MSWin_back_slash = 0;
```

in an initialization file (i.e., latexmkrc).

In versions 4.69a or higher of latexmk, you can also use the `-MSWinBackSlash-` option on the command line.  An example:

```
latexmk -cd- -MSWinBackSlash- -xelatex new/main
```

Then `xelatex` will be invoked with `/` for the directory separator rather than `\`.  For a further explanation of what's going on and why, look for the details on the `$MSWin_back_slash` variable in the documentation for v. 4.69a and up of latexmk.